# Blazor access to hardware

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I currently use **inject IJSRuntime** along with **navigator.geolocation, navigator.mediaDevices**
But is it correct? Isn't it possible to access these functions without javascript using only C#?
What do you think about it ?
Thank you for your feedback.
Daniel Kminek

Answer (score 1):

I'm am researching this question right now, and the answer is *No* you have to use JSInterop.  And *Yes* it can be done through Interop.  For an example of GeoLocation, see Ed Charbeneau's ebook [Blazor: A Beginners Guide](https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorBookExamples) and I've linked to the backing source code.  Also checkout [AspNetMonsters/Blazor.Geolocation](https://github.com/AspNetMonsters/Blazor.Geolocation)  I've used it for months and it is great.

Regarding MediaDevices: I've written some JS Interop/Blazor code and verified Blazor can see it, but not much further progress.  Can't find any examples, unlike Geolocation.

I can't really shed any light why you can't access the devices from C#.  Above my pay grade.  But I guess it could be API's not available from the Browser (which is really what has access to the hardware), or the underlying Blazor circuit.  If I make any headway, I'l update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/)  it can help you **access Browsers Geolocation services** as well. See [Geo JS docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/JsInterop.md#geolocation-js-see-demo-app) as well as [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/jsinterop#geo-js).

[image]